# Computer doesn't boot, continuously restarts; possible disk error

Tags: hard-drive, boot, multi-boot, reboot

I have shut down my computer two hours ago. When I open my computer it started restarting itself after showing the POST screen. I can open my computer with a Ubuntu Live CD or Windows installation CD. I can also open and boot my computer with my second drive, so I think something is wrong with my primary hard drive.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be and how can I fix it?

I am using an HP DV9087EA laptop and my primary disk is a WD500GB. I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 on my drive.

I can not reach boot screen. My laptop do not have disk diagnostic option in bios.

Comment: Does it reach the windows loading screen?
If so, can you access safe mode? (Press F8 before the windows loading screen appears)

Comment: F10 into the bios and run the hard drive diagnostics.

Comment: If it's trying to boot into Windows, use the Advanced boot options(in the F8 menu, if you can get to it) to Disable automatic restart on system failure. Then see if it gives you a Stop error to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from the Utimate Boot CD, and use one of the accompanying diagnostics to check the disk.

Or boot into you Ubuntu partition and install/run your chosen disk utility.

Answer (score 1):

Use F10 to enter the bios and then [run the hard drive diagnostics](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/How-to-test-RAM-and-HDD-Hard-Drive/td-p/301638)

Answer (score -1):

if the computer restarts right after POST and if you can boot from OS disc, then try access Recovery Environment and access other recovery tools like system restore

Comment: i was not able to reach boot menu.

Comment: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/start-the-windows-7-recovery-environment/

please try this...